# Collection View not reload every time

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I am using drag and drop functionality in collection view.its working fine but when I replace the values of array when user trap the cell into another position.I have reload the collection view.But when we drag and drop cell 0 and 1 collection view not reload all cell it reload only one cell.

I don't know what is the problem in my code.
Below is my code.

```
longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
        collection_view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell_images", for: indexPath) as! AddImagesCollectionViewCell
            cell.layer.borderWidth=1
            if Details.Images[indexPath.item].sourceType == sourceType.URL
            {
                cell.img_images.downloadedFrom(link: Details.Images[indexPath.item].imageURL!, contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
            }
            else
            {
                cell.img_images.image = Details.Images[indexPath.item].image
            }
            Details.Images[indexPath.row].sequence="\(indexPath.row + 1)"

            return cell

    }
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        if indexPath.row == Details.Images.count
        {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)")
        print("Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)")
        let tempArray =  Details.Images[sourceIndexPath.item]
        Details.Images.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
        Details.Images.insert(tempArray, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        switch(gesture.state)
        {
        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collection_view.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collection_view))
                else
            {
                break
            }
            if !(selectedIndexPath.row == Details.Images.count)
            {
                collection_view.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
            }
        case .changed:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collection_view.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collection_view))
                else
            {
                break
            }
            if !(selectedIndexPath.row == Details.Images.count)
            {
                collection_view.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))

            }
        case .ended:
            collection_view.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collection_view.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue. Don't know why `reloadData()` isn't working after `endInteractiveMovement()` or `cancelInteractiveMovement()`, but I have a workaround for this.

Instead of using `reloadData()` use `reloadSections()`, like:

```
self.collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()

// Not working: self.collectionView.reloadData()
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
}
```

Also if you use `reloadData()` in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` it will work.

Comment: On which method you implented this ?

Comment: In the method I call cancelInteractiveMovement / endInteractiveMovement. Check the code fragment I posted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bugs in your code, collectionView will reload only one cell (one you have draged).If you want to reload all collection view you need to call reloadData() after `endInteractiveMovement()`.

Comment: But some time it reloads all cells.

Comment: Not working after I reload call in endInteractiveMovement()

Comment: it reloads some time cause you write collectionView.reloadData() in collectionView:moveItem ... i suppose your reordering is canceled with some reasons set a breakpoint on collection_view.cancelInteractiveMovement() to check it, also add reloadData() after canceling.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with reordering via drag-and-drop - the collection view won't reload all the cells whose positions change because of the move operation. I fixed it by calling [`moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618059-moveitematindexpath?language=objc) in my implementation of [`performDropWithCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropdelegate/2897304-collectionview?language=objc). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57084818/412107).