# What is the role of UICollectionViewDataSource canMoveItemAtIndexPath when reordering via drag-and-drop?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

As of iOS 11, UICollectionView supports reordering using the [drag-and-drop APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views?language=objc). In my implementation of [`collectionView:performDropWithCoordinator:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropdelegate/2897304-collectionview?language=objc), I do something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *srcPath = [self somehowGetSourceIndexPathForDrag];
NSIndexPath *dstPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath;
[self.dataSource moveItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath];
[self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:srcPath toIndexPath:dstPath];
[coordinator dropItem:myDragItem toItemAtIndexPath:dstPath];
```

Everything works nicely. I find, though, that if I implement [`canMoveItemAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618015-collectionview?language=objc), it gets called, but everything works no matter what I return. If I implement [`moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618064-collectionview?language=objc), it doesn't get called.

So is there a point to using `canMoveItem` and `moveItem` in this scenario? Or should I just remove them?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If you do not implement this method, but you do implement the collectionView:moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: method, the collection view allows all items to be reordered.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618015-collectionview?language=objc